# jQuqey UI returning wrong date when using dateFormat and altFormat

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

## HTML

```
datepicker:<br />
<input id="datepicker-1" type="text"/>
```

## JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datepicker-1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "d M",
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        altFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        minDate: new Date(2015, 4, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(2017, 6, 31),
        onSelect: function(){
            var myDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); 
            console.log('current date: ' + myDate);
        }
    })
});
```

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer/cr3zo7xr/

For example, choose "*may 20, 2015*" in datepicker and So, *getDate* method shows 2014 year instead of 2015

[image]

If I remove `dateFormat: "d M"` *getDate* method shows correct date

[image]

**The question is:**

Why does getDate method show incorrect year with `dateFormat: "d M"` enabled?

Comment: Creating a JSFiddle is nice. Giving the correct link is better.

Comment: if year is not defined in dateFormat i.e only "d M" then it will pick the system year.

Comment: @MrUpsidown thanks for notice, link is fixed.

Comment: `dateFormat: "d M yy"` and you will get the right year.

Comment: @JibranKhan Khan, thank you, but in project I need to use exactly 'd M' format.

Comment: Then why are you bothering about the year ?

Comment: @JibranKhan, because I need correct current date to get + 30 days: `var myDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');               myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 30);                $('#second-datepicker').datepicker('setDate', myDate);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct `dateFormat`. If you want `myDate` to be in `'d M'` format you can do:

```
var myDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('d M', $(this).datepicker('getDate'));
```

Full example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datepicker-1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "d M yy",
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        altFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        minDate: new Date(2015, 4, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(2017, 6, 31),
        onSelect: function(){
            var myDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('d M', $(this).datepicker('getDate'));
            console.log(myDate);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small problem here with `dateFormat` and `altFormat`.

- `dateFormat` will changed the current input's element value and will also be used to parse the date
- `altFormat` takes the value and save it with a different format **in another input** specified by *altField*

You can use this field as a hidden input to store the data. In the example below I will leave this field as text so you can see the results.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     
    $("#datepicker-2").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
    $("#datepicker-1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "d M",
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        altFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        altField: '#alt-format',
        minDate: new Date(2015, 4, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(2017, 6, 31),
        onSelect: function(n, o){
            var myDate = $.datepicker.parseDate(o.settings.altFormat, $(o.settings.altField).val());  
                // this will parse the date of the hidden input with the format of altFormat
            $('#result').text('current date: ' + myDate);
          
          myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 30);
          $('#datepicker-2').datepicker('setDate', myDate);
          
        }
    });
    
});
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


datepicker:<br />
<input id="datepicker-1" type="text"/>
<input id="alt-format" type='text'/>

<input id="datepicker-2" type="text"/>


<br/><br/>
<div id='result'></div>
```